# How to parse HH:mm:ss+/-HH:MM into a date object?

Tags: java, parsing, date, time

I have an hour time 17:00:00-07:00 and I want to convert/parse it into (10 AM). How should I do it?

Comment: Parse each object separately, then perform your `Date` operations.

Comment: You should have a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Does it need to be a Date object? If you're using Java 8, you may want to look at the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and [java.time.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) APIs.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a date object, I need to convert the 17:00:00-07:00 into the actual time (10AM).

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems like a good question to me, without duplicates. I cannot find an answer in Joda-Time as the LocalTime parsing ignores the offset rather than using it to adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Incorrect Question

The question assumes the result should be 10 AM (`10:00:00`). That is incorrect.

According to the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard and others, the offset of `-07:00` means "behind [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) by 7 hours". Do not read it as an algebraic formula with a subtraction sign. Just the opposite, flip the sign to make a formula to get to [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

So the value `17:00:00-07:00` adjusts to `00:00:00` (the next day). Adding seven hours to 5 PM takes you to **midnight**.

## Solution

I thought at first that the answer could be found using a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to parse and then instantiate a LocalTime class in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). But the local time parsers ignore (truncate) the offset rather than apply it as an adjustment.

So as a workaround I use [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) to parse the time as if occurring in the first day of the Unix epoch (beginning of 1970 UTC). Then I switch to a LocalTime object.

```
String input = "17:00:00-07:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "HH:mm:ssZ" ); 
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( input ).withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
LocalTime localTime = dateTime.toLocalTime();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "localTime: " + localTime );
```

When run. Note how adding 7 hours to 5 PM takes us to the stroke of midnight, the first moment of the next day (*January 2 rather than 1*).

```
dateTime: 1970-01-02T00:00:00.000Z
localTime: 00:00:00.000
```

### Prepend `T` For ISO 8601 Input

If you prepend a `T` to the input string to comply with ISO 8601, you can use Joda-Time's built-in default parser to omit a line of code.

```
String input = "T" + "17:00:00-07:00"; // Prepend a "T" to comply with ISO 8601 format.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input ).withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ); // Pass standard string to constructor of DateTime. Or pass to static method DateTime.parse().
LocalTime localTime = dateTime.toLocalTime();
```

Comment: How do I parse this 17:00:00-07:00 to become -> 5pm and ignore the time offset?

Comment: @user3709877 Apply a [desired time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) such as "America/Los_Angeles" as seen in 2nd line calling `withZone` in last example above (recommended). Or learn about the [`withOffsetParsed`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withOffsetParsed()) method if you are sure you want to adjust away the offset (may be tempting, but probably not the best approach).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `parse` method of the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class with an appropriate pattern for your input string. This will convert it into a date object. If you want to convert back into a string with another format, use the `format` method of another  `SimpleDateFormat` object. But mind your time zones.

Here is some example code, **relying only on the standard Java libraries**:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

class TimeTest {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        String [] testData = {
            "17:00:00-07:00",
            "19:00:00+03:00",
            "15:04:00-10:00"
        };

        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "HH:mm:ssXXX" );
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "h:mm a" );
        outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        for ( String str: testData ) {
            try {
                Date dateObj = inputFormat.parse( str );
                System.out.println(str + " -> " + outputFormat.format(dateObj));
            } catch ( ParseException e ) {
                System.err.println( "Could not parse " + str );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output from this code is:

```
17:00:00-07:00 -> 12:00 AM
19:00:00+03:00 -> 4:00 PM
15:04:00-10:00 -> 1:04 AM
```

Comment: I've checked with SimpleDateFormat and it doesn't seem to support +/-HH:MM

Comment: The part that comes after the +/- in that time format, assuming it's the common one, actually indicates the time zone. So I believe pattern X should work.

Comment: @RealSkeptic So show some code to run rather than conjecture.